React-Vite React-Bootstrap build process problem
I'm trying to deploy a react vite application on github pages and during the build process these files are generated...
vite v5.2.11 building for production...
✓ 358 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                   0.47 kB │ gzip:  0.30 kB
dist/assets/index-BkBapJ-0.css  234.33 kB │ gzip: 31.52 kB
dist/assets/index-BEySFAnO.js   208.20 kB │ gzip: 67.42 kB
✓ built in 725ms
However my deployed application is blank screen and i have these console errors
GET https://cazbella.github.io/assets/index-BEySFAnO.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) and it isn't finding the files. Can you help?
I have imported bootstrap everywhere!
Many thanks.
I have tried removing bootstrap and react bootstrap individually and the files are still built in the build process and cause the errors

I found the answer, I needed a ./ as the base, not just / !
